# Highligh Cell Border according to selection (Active cell)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just have a simple HTML table and I need to highlight the selected cell.

```
<table with='100%'>

<tr>
    <td> 
    <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" id="x1">
    <label for="x1"><A></label>

    </td>

<td> 
    <input type="radio" name="x" value="2" id="x2">
    <label for="x2"><B></label>

    </td>

<td > 
    <input type="radio" name="x" value="3" id="x3">
    <label for="x3"><C></label>

    </td>

</tr>


<tr>
    <td> 
    <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" id="x4">
    <label for="x4"><D></label>

    </td>


<td> 
    <input type="radio" name="x" value="2" id="x5">
    <label for="x5"><E></label>

    </td>


<td > 
    <input type="radio" name="x" value="3" id="x6">
    <label for="x6"><F></label>

    </td>

</tr>

</table>
```

THE CSS:
    td.rata { border: 5px solid #ccc; padding:3px }

```
$('td').click(function () {
  $('this').toggleClass("rata");
});
```

The requirement is as follows: If the user selects the cell "A" an outline (border) will be shown on A, If the user selects the cell "B" an outline (border) will be shown on "B" and remove from cell "A", and so on...

Thanks

Comment: how do you define selected here?

Comment: You should use valid markup; e.g., `<A">` is not valid. Do not use placeholders that would constitute markup if actually used on a page. Also please specify whether you want a border or an outline. They are two different things (in CSS). And please specify how this relates to JavaScript and jQuery, if it does.

Comment: There was an error in the mark up, i fixed...But my question is not answered yet...Thanks anyhow

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr td label').click(function(){
$('.border').removeClass('border');
$(this).parent('td').addClass('border');
});
```

CSS:
    .border
    {
   border:1px solid red;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('td').click(function () {
    $('td').removeClass("rata");
    $(this).addClass("rata");
 });
```